# Is there a way to parse an image for text? The text will always be the same

Tags: node.js, image-processing

My situation:

My application(AWS lamdba) makes requests to external party to get static images; I pass along an id in the request.

For every valid id, I would get a 200 response with a valid image.

For every invalid id; ie gibberish, I would get a 200 response with an image that has the following text: "Image is not available for this id". The text is always that BUT the size will vary(technically, I can pass the size to the API so I could first send a request for a "tiny" image then parse that for "invalid image").

Is there a way to using nodejs to parse the image quickly to check if I got an image that has that text?

I see a lot of image manipulation modules but nothing that does what I was looking for.

PS: am node js noob.

PPS: no the external party won't change their API to return a 400/4.

Comment: You say the text will always be the same - but will the image always be the same? If so, you could md5 checksum the image and compare against the standardised "Image not available" image.

Comment: Agree..you can go with OCR, but...if the invalid image response is always the same, just store that invalid image's data and compare it to every new response image. As stated above you can easily compare the md5 checksum..

Comment: @MarkSetchell ah forgot, the text will always be the same but the size wont ...

Comment: @cviejo what is OCR? could you link me?

Comment: ive updated op with a few more details.

Comment: @cviejo i got the OCR meaning. quick google got me this https://github.com/joscha/nodecr i wonder if this is good since last update was over 2 years.

Comment: There's a [number of modules](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=OCR) you can try, you'd have to try them out and see which one does the job for you.

Comment: If the *"Image not available"* picture is just one colour text on another colour solid background and the real pictures are more complicated photos with lots of colours and variations, you don't need full OCR, you can look for just a small number of colours and a tiny standard deviation more simply.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the valid images is a chart with maybe 3-5 different colors; the invalid image is literally "image not avail" in black on white bg. i like your idea of md5, tho i'll look to see if avoid that.